# How to fix the Cannot find module mp3 file or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-hooks

[image]

How to fix the error Cannot find module './audio/audio1.mp3' or its corresponding type declarations. also already use the `require('./audio/audio1.mp3')` and also getting an error.

Answer (score 3):

Inside the `src/react-app-env.d.ts` add this:

```
/// <reference types="react-scripts" />
    declare module '*.mp3'; // '*.wav' if you're using wav format
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
import audio1 from './audio/audio.mp3';

const myAudio = new Audio(audio1);
```

Comment: already tried that one. still getting the error

Comment: Have made an edit. You can try it

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found